# How to know which version of PyMongo is running on my project

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm developing a python project, in the requirements file  I have three different types of PyMongo

```
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
pymongo==2.7
flask-mongoengine==0.7.1
```

How can I define which version I'm using?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you got `pip` installed, you can try this in terminal:

```
$ pip freeze | grep pymongo
pymongo==3.0.2
```

Comment: The result of that command is: pymongo==3.0, none of them above!

Comment: @Egzona So, that's the version of pymongo you've installed. You can force to install it by ``pip install pymongo==2.7``, ``sudo`` maybe required. BTW, virtualenv is suggested to isolate different projects' environments, although not needed.

Answer (score 21):

You can learn like this,

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.version
'3.0.3'
```

Comment: Also for this command result is: pymongo==3.0, none of them above!

Comment: I have installed 3.0.3, depends your installation.  What is your results?

Comment: After executing your command result is: pymongo==3.0, but in my project in requirement file version of it is different, I can't  understand why is happening this?

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
python -c 'import pymongo; print (pymongo.__version__)'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pymongo
print("Mongo version",pymongo.__version__)
```

Works perfectly in python3

Comment: I know this question is very old but this answer tells about python3 version display I hope this helps few new people.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip list | grep pymongo
```

or

```
pip freeze | grep pymongo
```

Comment: While this might be a possible solution. it is encouraged to explain how or why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to grep; For Windows installs using Conda environments with pip this worked for me:

```
pip freeze | findstr /si pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

open the command prompt 
IF your python path is set , simply write 
pip freeze 
it shows the versions of all packages installed , including pymongo