# 'collection_names' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to deploy this project on ubuntu 20 server

https://github.com/dcai/airnotifier/wiki/Installation-3.x

I followed all the steps but when I try to run the install.py file I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 64, in <module>
    collection_names = masterdb.collection_names()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 3194, in __call__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'collection_names' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

- Python Version is: 3.8.10
- MongoDB Version is: 6.0.3

Can anyone advice what should I do?

Comment: What version of PyMongo? https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#database-collection-names-is-removed

Comment: @user20042973 how to know it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221694/how-to-know-which-version-of-pymongo-is-running-on-my-project

Comment: @user20042973 4.2.0

Comment: Then I think that link explains the problem - airnotifier hasn't been updated in a few years. You are using a PyMongo version that is newer than what it supports. You need to downgrade PyMongo (or update the airnotifier code) for the two to be compatible

Comment: airnotifier code is not updated, so how can I downgrade the PyMongo and to which version.

Comment: Did you follow the steps precisely? `pipenv install --deploy` installs pymongo 3.5.1 and `pipenv run ./install.py` uses this exact version. The error suggests a way younger version of pymongo is being picket up by `import`